# can't access listBox1

Tags: c#

I have listBox1 but when I am using that listBox1  inside the buttonClick I can access but outside the buttonClick I can't access .
Where I am doing mistakes ? Thanks

```
namespace design
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(button1.Text);// I can access listBox1 here...
        }

        listBox1.//I can't access listBox1 here....
    }
}
```

Comment: Observe the error and search on net. Its very basic C# !

Comment: When do you want the code to run? Forms are event driven so the code will only run when inside a method. If you need it to run straight away make a form load event.

Comment: Why do you wanna access your list at that point? Must have a reason!

Comment: I am new so I didn't know that. I mean no reason :) And also when I can use like that?or Can I use like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You need to put `listBox1` inside some method to access it.

```
namespace design
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(button1.Text); // This part is inside a event click of a button. This is why you can access this.
        }

        public void accessList()
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(button1.Text); // You'll be able to access it here. Because you are inside a method.
        }
        // listBox1. // you'll NEVER access something like this. in this place
    }
}
```

[Maybe you wanna do a property ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean with "do a property" ?What can I do with it ?

Comment: `A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field. Properties can be used as if they are public data members, but they are actually special methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily and still helps promote the safety and flexibility of methods.` [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). Also take a look at [C# - When to use properties instead of functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374273/c-sharp-when-to-use-properties-instead-of-functions)

Comment: No problem. We try to help everyone, so they could help us in future! ^_^

Answer (score 12):

You **can** access it there but it's not working because you are not in any function or method.

You can't just start typing code somewhere in a class, you need to handle some kind of event or something.

This is very basic C# knowledge btw.

Comment: I can't see listBox1 there.And everytime am I have to use in function or method?why ?

Comment: How else would the compiler know when to execute your code? C# is an event-driven language. I suggest you find some tutorials on the internet or a good book to study.

Comment: Ok now understood that I have use in function or method.you said you can access but I can't see with intellisense.

Comment: If you are in a place where it is valid to access the listbox you can see it in IntelliSense