# C# Overwrite methods or Overwrite accessors for constant return

Tags: c#, methods, overriding, accessor

**Hello.**

I have a class hierarchy. Classes are read from a binary file. They are distinguished by a code that is at the beginning of their binary encoding. I want to use that code to distinguish them.

I wondered what would be the best choice for each class to return its type, overwrite a method or overwrite an accessor.

Let me give an example in which 3 classes inherit from an abstract class... a chunk of code speaks a thousand words.

// ENUM WITH TYPE CODES

```
enum CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE : byte
{
    CONCRETE_0 = 0xCA,
    CONCRETE_1 = 0xFE,
    CONCRETE_2 = 123
}
```

// OPTION A: OVERRIDE METHODS

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE type();
}

class ConcreteClass0 : AbstractClass
{
    public override CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE type()
    {
        return CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE.CONCRETE_0;
    }
}

class ConcreteClass1 : AbstractClass
{
    public override CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE type()
    {
        return CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE.CONCRETE_1;
    }
}

class ConcreteClass2 : AbstractClass
{
    public override CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE type()
    {
        return CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE.CONCRETE_2;
    }
}
```

// OPTION B: OVERRIDE ACCESSORS

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE type {get;}
}

class ConcreteClass0 : AbstractClass
{
    public override CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE type
    {
        get { return CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE.CONCRETE_0; }
    }
}

class ConcreteClass1 : AbstractClass
{
    public override CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE type
    {
        get { return CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE.CONCRETE_1; }
    }
}

class ConcreteClass2 : AbstractClass
{
    public override CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE type
    {
        get { return CONCRETE_CLASS_TYPE.CONCRETE_2; }
    }
}
```

**What would be the advantages and disadvantages?**

The advantage I've seen to overwrite methods is that the code would be more easily translated into other languages if it did by hand.

The advantage I've seen in use accessors is spare write 2 parentheses whenever I need to know the type and that is semantically more correct.

What other advantages or disadvantages you see in the options? Is one more efficient than the other?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Maybe use methods is more faster, because all things we can do with the accessors (Like parsing a JSON) must have a cost, and methods can only be "called".

Comment: when asking about efficiency, you'll need to benchmark it yourself. In terms of advantages and disadvantages, you'll find that you're repeating yourself. A lot. Imagine if you hard 1000 class types; this means 1000 enum constants and 1000 overwrites... Is there perhaps a better way to retrieve the objects (are you given the binary files or could you store the objects a different way)?

Comment: I may of mis-read the question, is the question about Properties and Function? `String item{ get{ return ""; } }` over `string item() { return ""; } ?

Comment: You're absolutely right @"Ben Knoble", I'm a bad boy for no auto-answer myself.

Comment: @BenKnoble I gonna use methods, 4 Java easy porting, make the test, post the program&results and I will mark the answer as valid :*. Or the answer of anyone that do it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is no advantage really, if you need to pass parameters or need to do a lengthy calculation then use a function, but if you're returning or setting a local variable that is private and you need to run a check before setting or getting the variable use a property, that is my viewing of using properties or functions

---

Another question like this is here [When to use properties instead of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374273/when-to-use-properties-instead-of-functions)

[Question answered by : [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374291/2801045)]

When using properties thing if the property will :

- return a single, logic value
- Little or no logic is involved (typically just return a value, or do a small check/return value)

When to use functions think of if the result value will require :

- There is going to be significant work involved in returning the value - ie: it'll get fetched from a DB, or something that may take "time"
- There is quite a bit of logic involved, either in getting or setting the value

---

In addition, I'd recommend looking at [Microsoft's Design Guidelines for Property Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d%28VS.71%29.aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1).  They suggest:

> Use a property when the member is a logical data member.
>
> Use a method when:
>
> - The operation is a conversion, such as Object.ToString.
> - The operation is expensive enough that you want to communicate to the user that they should consider caching the result.
> - Obtaining a property value using the get accessor would have an observable side effect.
> - Calling the member twice in succession produces different results.
> - The order of execution is important. Note that a type's properties should be able to be set and retrieved in any order.
> - The member is static but returns a value that can be changed.
> - The member returns an array. Properties that return arrays can be very misleading. Usually it is necessary to return a copy of the internal array so that the user cannot change internal state. This, coupled with the fact that a user can easily assume it is an indexed property, leads to inefficient code. In the following code example, each call to the Methods property creates a copy of the array. As a result, 2n+1 copies of the array will be created in the following loop.

Answer (score 1):

Both are bad solutions as both indulge in diffusion of responsibility. You have spread the responsibilty for determining a class from an enum and four classes.

Instead, have a factory class that is responsible for providing a class type based on the code. In crude terms, the code might be:

```
Type GetTypeBasedonCode(int code)
{
    if (code == 0xCA)
    {
        return typeof(ConcreteType0);
    }
    if (code == 0xFE)
    {
        return typeof(ConcreteType1);
    }
    return typeof(ConcreteType2);
}
```

There are better ways of implementing such a factory, but the key is that code/type matching is in one place, making it easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @David Arno.
Maybe I should not have called the method/function "type", because it leads to confusion.

Comment: I do not return class types I return integer type, which can be used to make switch, if i use it in the future, I Hope Not, this would show a bad design.

Comment: With Type we can't use a Switch. Switch an integer type is a little faster than use (AbstractObject is ConcreteObject) else (AbstractObject is ConcreteObject2) and so on.

Comment: Using overrides, I forced to define the return in new sub-classes when i writing it.

Comment: The types are all together in the enum.

I do not want to get the Class Type from the code , but if I want, your answer would be valid.